# Question about line splitting when reading text file

Tags: python

Why can I split my list while I'm opening my file? I know that you shouldn't be able to split a list. Can anyone help explain the concept behind this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9lvS.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Why should you not be able to split a list?

Comment: You're not splitting a list, you're splitting a string.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You should have added `print(type(i))` like in the code below

```
from typing import List

with open("test.txt") as file1:
    fh = file1.readlines()
    for i in fh:
        print(type(i)) # <class 'str'> 
        file2 = i.split(":")
```

Here, i is a string not a list and therefore you can use split whose return type is a list.

If you need more examples, check the documentation of split : https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html